# How to get goconvey working on windows 7?

Tags: windows, go, goconvey

I'm starting to work on some development work with golang and I would love to use the BDD style goconvey gives.

I've just configured my system to be set up for golang, I've go get github.com/smartystreets/goconvey all good, but when I write some simple tests in goconvey and try to execute them via the console I get

```
$go test -v
go build github.com/smartystreets/assertions: no buildable Go source files in 
FAIL go-tdd-take1 [build failed]
```

Are there any tricks to getting it working in windows?

I am working behind a proxy but I I'm not sure if this is a problem here, I believe I've configured it ok.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've now listed `github.com/smartystreets/assertions` in root of the project, which should ensure that it gets pulled in the first time. https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/commit/1d9daca83fc3cf35d01b9d0ac2debad3453bf178

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think I've figured it out.
Looks as though when I installed goconvey it did not download the assertions in the convey directory
So once I $go get github.com/smartystreets/assertions
then copied that directory to there it should have gone it seemed to work.

This is still a little odd, I'm assuming that the proxy had something to do with it, I know it took a longer time to install than on my mac without a proxy.

Comment: "then copied that directory" ... woah! You shouldn't need to copy anything around after a `go get`/`go install` if you've set your [GOPATH remotely sanely](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).